# Email validation solution for front and backend

Tags: java, javascript, regex, validation, email

We have to do email validation and there are a large number of solution. The email is not the primary email we are using across site so we are not planning on sending a email and verifying the account. Hence we we are relying on regex based validation solution.

Now doing regex based validation in server-side(java) is generally discouraged and we are advised to use existing solution like [EmailValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/javadocs/api-1.4.0/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html) or existing libraries. Now the problem is to achieve consistency between front end validation(which would be regex based and implemented in javascript) and backend implementation (which will be in java).

Is there a solution to achieve consistency between these validation on front-end and backend automatically.

Comment: Note that EmailValidator (version 1.4.0, the latest at the time of writing) is behind the time. It will fail to validate `.moe` or `.ninja`, which are valid TLDs. The current code also doesn't support internationalized domain names.

Answer (score 1):

I see two solutions, that might not the most optimal but that are certainly worth a try.

1) You could implement a web-service that would return the result returned by EmailValidator and then call this webservice in your javascript to do the checks.

2) Try to find the regex used by EmailValidator (assuming they use a regex), and use the same in your javascipt.